# Save/Open events in PowerPoint web addin

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, office365api, powerpoint-addins

Is there any Save/Open events available for PowerPoint Web Addin. We need to perform some operations during these events. We searched office documentations provided in Microsoft site for the events, but not found anything suitable yet.

Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-handle-open-and-save-event-from-powerpoint/ed8062ae-617e-4b84-a66e-a7d5ef1349ba

Comment: We have already checked those tutorials. But there is no option to get Open/Save events 
 for the PowerPoint in those documentation. But the same is available for Word and Excel add-ins.